# can I specify categories for jestjs tests and select which categories to run?

Tags: jestjs

How do I run a select set of tests in Jest?

In Behat I can tag tests and run just the tests bearing a given tag.

Some form of tagging must be possible in Jest, right? If so, how?

Comment: no, it is [not supported](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1520) so far. and nothing else like that.